# Does the function second exists in scala?

Tags: scala

I am trying the below code and I can find head and tail methods in scala documentation for Vector (https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.2/scala/collection/immutable/Vector.html)  but I can't find second method in scala API.

How can this code works ? It returns 2

```
Vector(1, 2, 3, 4) match {
  case head +: second +: tail => second
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pattern matching on a list in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13057668/pattern-matching-on-a-list-in-scala) - note esp. answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57135284/16673

Comment: Note that this code is very inefficient since **Vector** is not intended to be used like that. It would be better to use **List** which would be efficient or using `apply` on the **Vector** that would also be efficient. Also, this function is unsafe since it will _throw_ if the collection doesn't have at leas 2 elements.

Answer (score 3):

In this situation, `head`, `second` and `tail` are not methods. They are simply identifiers for values that will be used for capturing the pattern in pattern matching.

You can rename them to `first`, `second` and `theRest`. It will still work.

For more info, read about pattern matching in Scala and how it utilizes the `unapply` method to match and extract the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

What you see is a pattern matching and in this context most things are not what they seem to be at first sight. The pattern matching has a carefully create set of rules which results in a code working kind of backwards.

There is no function `second`. In your example not even `head` or `tail` are functions. They are identifiers which are used as a target to the pattern matching (extractor). Not even `+:` is a function in this context - it is a carefully crafted extractor object with an `unapply` method.

You could name `head`, `second` and `tail` as `a`, `b` and `c` and the code would still work (gotcha: you cannot name them as `Head`, `Second` and `Tail`).

Now you know the keywords (*pattern matching*, *extractor*, *unapply*), you can find plenty of articles explaining this, the one I like most is [The Neophyte's Guide to Scala Part 1: Extractors](https://danielwestheide.com/blog/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-1-extractors/).